# Phpmailer smtp 500 error hosting error

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to use phpmailer. At first my script worked but now I get a internal server error 500 when I execute this script. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my script:

```
 require('class.phpmailer.php');
        require("class.smtp.php");
        $mail           = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->Host       = 'mx1.hostinger.nl'; 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = true; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;     
        $mail->Host       = 'mx1.hostinger.nl'; 
        $mail->Port       = 2525;
        $mail->Username   = 'EMAIL'; 
        $mail->Password   = 'PASSWORD';
        $mail->SetFrom('EMAIL', 'NAME'); 
        $mail->AddReplyTo('EMAIL','NAME'); 
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Subject    = 'Kortingsbon aanmelding NAME nieuwsbrief';

        $mail->AltBody    = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = '<table width="100%"; rules="all" style="border:1px solid #3A5896;" cellpadding="10"><tr><td><img src="LOGOLOCATION/logo.png" alt="ALTTEKST" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2>Beste Klant,<br /><br />Bedankt voor uw aanmelding voor onze nieuwsbrief met e-mailadres <strong>'.$email.'</strong>. <br />Hieronder vindt u de kortingsbon. Print deze kortingbon uit zodat u gebruik kunt maken van deze actie bij uw volgende aankoop. Wij hopen u binnenkort weer te begroeten in onze winkel!</td></tr><tr><td colspan=2><i>Wordt uw kortingsbon hieronder niet weegegeven? Klik dan op inhoud toestaan, vertrouw afzender of afbeeldingen weergeven bij uw e-mailprogramma.</i> <br /> <img height="488" width="650" src="PICTURRE/'.$maand.'.JPG" alt="kortingscode foto" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2>Dit is een automatische e-mail en u kunt er daarom niet op reageren. 
        <p style="font-size: 10px">U kunt zich altijd weer <a href="WEBSITE">uitschrijven</a></p></td></tr></table>';
        $mail->Send();
if (!$mail->send()) {
$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: look at your server's error log. it'll have details about the 500. without any of that, we can NOT help you.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$mail->ErrorInfo;
```

That is a simple syntax error - you can't just type a property name and hope it does something. Change it to this:

```
echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

While you're there, update to latest PHPMailer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I use the latest version (5.2.9).
Changed your suggestion but I still get the 500error. When I remove the entire line: 

`if(!$mail->Send()) {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
 echo "Message sent!";
 }` 


The script executes without problems, but no mail of course.

Comment: So what does your mail server log or SMTP transcript say?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem (error 500) on hostinger. I might be wrong but it seems that they've blocked port 2525 and 25. This is working perfectly fine for me. I hope this would help you.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SMTPDebug = false;                               

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'xyz@gmail.com';                 
$mail->Password = 'pass';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                    


$mail->setFrom('xyz@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com');               
$mail->addReplyTo('xyz@gmail.com', 'Information');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Body';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```